# ASP.NET MVC ActionResult not showing image on IPad

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery datepicker that populates an image src using a Url.Action.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                inline: true,
                altField: '#selecteddate',
                altFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                onSelect: function () {
                    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
                    $('#diary img').attr(
                        'src',
                        '<%= Url.Action("Image") %>/' + date.val().toString());
                }
            });
        });        
    </script>
```

The image is an in memory bitmap converted to a png using the following action on my controller

```
public class ImageResult : ActionResult
{
    Image image;

    public ImageResult(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png"; 

        image.Save(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);                         
        image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The image displays fine however the image src does not have an extension so it shows as /2012-07-11 how can I add the extension .png? as without I believe it stops it showing on an Ipad.

Comment: Are you using the default route pattern for this image's URL? Please post the route and the corresponding URL that gets rendered on the browser. At the very least, you should be able to show the .png extension using a custom route.

Comment: yes am using the default route pattern - the image comes out as follows <img alt="" src="/Tunnel/Image/2012-07-11"> pretty sure I just need to add .png on the end of the date. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate a new route that has the `.png` extension built in:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Image", // Route name
   "tunnel/image/{id}.png", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Tunnel", action = "Image" }            
);
```

And update your javascript like so:

`'tunnel/image/' + date.val().toString() + '.png';`